# Svelte API proxy cors

Tags: cors, frontend, rollup, svelte

I am not sure if this belongs here, but I am having issues with developing my svelte app.
During development it is currently running on a standalone server (followed a guide that is using rollup and sirv) and targeting a backend API on a different port.

Later on these will be merged, but for now during development I am seeing a lot of cors issues(which makes sense) and since I am not currently able to change the backend I am wondering what the normal course of action is to get this working?

I assume that I should somehow create a middleware proxy that somehow ties into rollup, but I am far from sure about how.

So any suggestions on how I can set this up?

just tested running with this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-cors-proxy
but that did not work, because I need to have `credentials: "include"` for a particular fetch request and it results in `The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

Comment: Having a similar problem. Would you please consider editing the title - it could state a bit clearer what your problem is/was? Helps us.

Comment: issue was that the server API was on a different server than the svelte frontend during development. In prod they were on the same server. This caused issues with cors during development. I solved it by writing my own lightweight proxy with node and express that I could fire up when needed

Answer (score 8):

I ran in to the same issue today and with a little investigation in the Rollup ecosystem it seems that you could decide on using the [rollup-plugin-dev](https://github.com/pearofducks/rollup-plugin-dev) plugin which allows for a parameter `proxy` (with seems to use [koa-better-http-proxy](https://github.com/nsimmons/koa-better-http-proxy#usage)). With this plugin you could configure a proxy that even accepts custom functions to handle the requests, giving you control over what happens. Which is perhaps what you are looking for.

However I wanted to keep the live reloading in my application that is set up using the [rollup-plugin-livereload](https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-livereload) plugin. Yet as both the livereload and dev plugin provide their own server you can only use one at the same time.

Some more research presented me with [this article](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-and-rollup-the-same-but-different-a41ad427058c) by Rich Harris with as consensus a general rule that Rollup is used for library development and Webpack for application development. With this in mind I set up the [Webpack svelte template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template-webpack) which allows the configuration of the `devServer` with a `proxy` as described in their [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy). This is the route I took for my application.

Answer (score 0):

That is because local-cors-proxy uses the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) library, which has `*` as a default value for its `origin` option (which corresponds to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header).

You could modify your local copy of local-cors-proxy, editing `lib/index.js`, substituting the line `proxy.use(cors());` with:

```js
  proxy.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://yourapp.com'    // maybe 'http://127.0.0.1' in your case?
  }));
```

(or even better, add a cors customization option to local-cors-proxy and submit a PR so that other could benefit ;-)