# Svelte Proxy with rollup?

Tags: proxy, svelte

I'm trying to proxy requests from a Svelte app to a different port, where my backend API runs. I want to use a rollup proxy in the dev environment.
I read the alternative of using a webpack proxy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58877815/svelte-api-proxy-cors), but I want to give rollup proxy a try.
This is not an issue in production.

As suggested, I tried configuring [rollup-plugin-dev](https://github.com/pearofducks/rollup-plugin-dev) However, whenever I make a request to weatherforecast I still get an CORS error. Below is my configuration and the call:

```js
import dev from 'rollup-plugin-dev'

// other code

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
  plugins: [
        dev({ 
            proxy: [{ from: '/weatherforecast', to: 'https://localhost:7262' }] 
        }),
        // other code
    ];
```

and App.svelte looks like this:

```js
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    const endpoint = "/weatherforecast";

    onMount(async function () {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(endpoint);
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }       
    });
</script>
```

Any help in solving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Could you share the CORS error you get exactly?

Comment: I get `Status 404 Not Found / Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin` If I do the same call from a REST client, I get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure rollup-proxy on dev environment, you need to remove the call to the serve method, call the dev method and move the proxy calls inside the dev method:

```js
import dev from 'rollup-plugin-dev'

// other code

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {

        // other code

        commonjs(),

        // enable the rollup-plugin-dev proxy
        // call `npm run start` to start the server
        // still supports hot reloading
        !production && dev({
            dirs: ['public'],
            spa: 'public/index.html',
            port: 5000,
            proxy: [
                { from: '/weatherforecast', to: 'https://localhost:7262/weatherforecast' },
            ],
        }),

        // line below is no longer required
        // !production && serve(),

        // other code
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is the proxy is passing through the CORS headers un-touched, so you're basically interacting with the API as though the proxy wasn't even there, with respect to CORS.

I'll note that you *can* get around this in dev, but keep in mind this problem will come up in production too, so you may just need to rethink how you're getting this data.

For development though, you can use something like [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere). This is a middleware that you can run through your dev server that can rewrite the headers for you.